# Analyzing a large array quickly

Tags: java, arrays, performance

So, I would like to analyze the color of every single pixel on my screen very quickly.  To do so, I am using `Robot.getPixelColor(i, j)` inside a double-nested for loop where `i` is my screen width and `j` is my screen height.  This, of course, takes a very long time because I have a 1080 screen.  Any suggestions on how to speed the process up?  Right now it takes about an hour and I need it to take about 5 seconds.  Or is this just not possible?  Thanks in advance!!

Comment: How are you analyzing it? Code please?

Comment: Does your *analysis* of a pixel depend on any other pixel?

Comment: This depends on what kind of analysis you want to do. You could take a screenshot, reduce its size and do the analysis on this smaller image.

Comment: Basically, I'm going to have a Minecraft window open and I want to check if there is a tree on the screen as if a human were looking at it.  I was going to analyze the color of a tree with the pixels on the screen.

Comment: I think what I'm going to do is check every other 50 or so pixels rather than each one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the robot is good for getting the big picture and maybe for individual pixels

as for going ovel all pixels you get the image - I get about 50 times speedup.

```
  long tm=System.currentTimeMillis();
int i;
Toolkit it=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
  Dimension d=it.getScreenSize();
  int w=(int)d.getWidth(), h=(int)d.getHeight();
  Rectangle rect=new Rectangle(0, 0, w, h);
  Robot r=null;
  try {
    r=new Robot();
  }
  catch(AWTException awte){ };
  BufferedImage ib=r.createScreenCapture(rect);
  int[] pix=ib.getRGB(0, 0, w, h, null, 0, w);
  for(i=0; i<pix.length; i++) pix[i]=pix[i]&0x00ffffff;
      System.out.println("t1 "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-tm));
       tm=System.currentTimeMillis();
  for(i=0; i<pix.length; i++) r.getPixelColor(i%w, i/w);
      System.out.println("t2 "+(System.currentTimeMillis()-tm));
```